# Is this not mutating an immutable variable?

Tags: rust, immutability, mutability

How is it that I am allowed to do this?

```
fn procedure(param: f64) {
   println!("{}", param + 9);
```

But not allowed to do this without declaring mutable on the parameter?

```
fn procedure(mut param: f64) {
param += 9.;
println!("{}", param);
```

Is it because in the second function I act directly on the variable itself?

I'm trying to learn Ownership in Rust and I'm confused as to what is considered "mutating". Is there different rules for doing actions on variables that fill curly braces in print macros?
In my main function:

```
procedure(param_in_main);
println!("printing {} in main", param_in_main);
```

Both of the functions will give the same result without altering the passed variable. The video I am following as a guide places significance on mutability not altering the variable passed in main. But it didn't alter it to begin with in the first procedure. I think I am just misunderstanding what is being said but any feedback in regards to memory/copies in this case would be great.

Comment: `param + 9` is creating a new value without modifying (mutating) `param`. If you were to print `param` after that first print, you would find that it has the original value. In the second example, you are _modifying_ the value stored in the variable, which is why you have to declare it as mutable. Hope this helps.

Comment: That did help, thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Mutating** is about modifying an already defined value.
Arguments are named and already defined when the function is called.
Same when you define your own variables.

You code

```
fn procedure(param: f64) {
   println!("{}", param + 9);
```

is conceptually the same as

```
fn procedure(param: f64) {
   
   println!("{}", {let a0 = param + 9; a0});
```

Meaning that a temporary variable is created that stores the value of `param + 9` and then passed as argument to `println`. You're not mutating anything, you are just creating a new temporary variable.

Comment: Use a random name for the temp variable, perhaps (`let _v12342343 = ...` or something)? Because there's definitely no shadowing involved.

Comment: Would the shadowing cause an issue here? I figured that keeping the same name would make things clearer. I don't mind changing to a random name if it makes things clearer.

Comment: IMHO, shadowing makes things more confusing.

Comment: Changed it. I think you were right about clarity. Thanks!

Comment: @codegNo problem! Don't forget to mark this as solved! ;)